# Handling POSTDATA in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, http, post, sinatra, postdata

I'm trying to create a page in Sinatra, so that whatever you post (under the parameter name "command") will be echoed back to you. Here's my current approach:

```
post '/eval' do
  "I got #{params[:data][:command]}."
end
```

If I try to post anything to /eval, it results in an internal server error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that your `[:data]` param is `nil`. One way you could fix this is to remove the reference to `[:data]`. Try this instead.

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra"

post '/eval' do
  "I got #{params[:command]}."
end
```

you can test this with curl on your command line (if you are using a unix based system).

```
curl http://localhost:4567/eval -F "command=hello"
```

In the future, It will be helpful to others if you provide a stacktrace of your error with your question.